# Should I gitignore my .gitignore?

Tags: git, version-control

My concern is that since most of my projects are on GitHub, if someone else forks one of my projects and they use a different IDE than me, they will want to add all of their IDE-specific project files to the `.gitignore`. Then they will have to decide if they want to push those changes to the repository or not, and if they don't, then every time they pull, their modified `.gitignore` might have conflicts.

Am I worrying too much about the little things? What is the best practice? Is it worth it to track changes in your `.gitignore` or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't ignore the .gitignore file - for developer-specific ignore rules, there are two options:

- **Repository-specific ignore rules**:
  You can set ignore rules in the .git/info/exclude file.  It works exactly the same as the .gitignore file, but it's not part of the version controlled code.
- **Per-machine, global rules**:
  You can create a global git config file which has ignore rules for your IDE-specific configuration.  Just create a file anywhere on your machine and tell git to use it as the global ignore file: `git config --global core.excludesfile /path/to/ignorefile`

There's more thorough documentation on github:
https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: I didn't know about the `.git/info/exclude` file. That makes me think that maybe I should be putting my IDE project files in there or in my global excludes file instead of my `.gitignore`, and use the `.gitignore` only for generated files (logs, byecode, binaries etc.). Do you agree?

Comment: If you use the same IDE for most of your projects, you might want to use a global git config file for the IDE project files.  I usually prefer to keep the IDE config out of the committed .gitignore file, but I know people who feel the other way.

Comment: You should probably say "GitHub" and not "the git site" (I believe git's home page is actually [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com)).

Comment: Good point, should have payed more attention to what I was linking